# Windows 10 SSH server "permission denied" on login after changing computer name

Tags: windows, ssh, permissions, openssh

I am running an SSH server on Windows 10, the server was working well until I changed the computer name. Since then I cannot login through SSH.

I tried deleting the `Users\username\.ssh` folder on both server and client machines to force it to recreate the public key as well as reinstalling the OpenSSH Server. Trying to connect from the server itself using `ssh username@localhost` gets "permission denied".

I have a rule on the server's firewall that allows the OpenSSH Server.

I checked that the port is open on the server using `Test-NetConnection -Port 22 -ComputerName ip.of.server -InformationLevel Detailed` and got:

```
ComputerName            : ip.of.server
RemoteAddress           : ip.of.server
RemotePort              : 22
NameResolutionResults   : ip.of.server
                          HOME
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Private Network
IsAdmin                 : False
InterfaceAlias          : Ethernet
SourceAddress           : ip.of.client
NetRoute (NextHop)      : 0.0.0.0
TcpTestSucceeded        : True
```

Any ideas on what else to try?

Comment: So if you changed the computer name back to the original name does the problem still exhibit itself?  **Its only a test**